# How should I manage configuration for different environments in AngularJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs, gruntjs

How should I manage different environment settings in AngularJS projects? For example, I'd like to configure things like this different depending on whether I'm in development, test, staging or production:

- Redirect URLs for single sign on
- URLs for other services (especially those that support CORS or JSONP i.e. not on the same domain)

On the server side, in Django I'd use settings and local_settings or in Rails, I'd use different environment files like production.rb or development.rb. What's the best practice in AngularJS?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16339595/angular-js-configuration-for-different-enviroments

Comment: thanks DanS, yeah, we ended up going with ng-constant

Answer (score 1, accepted):

May be this lib https://www.npmjs.com/package/grunt-ng-constant could help u.

This question is related to [How do I configure different environments in Angular.js?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16339595/angular-js-configuration-for-different-enviroments)

Answer (score 1):

The solution we use is rather straight forward.
Django (or Flask in our case) passes a variable that contain all the api urls to the template where I transform it into a global javascript variable.

I then have a constant defined in Angularjs which fetches that variable. At this point all my services use that constant to retrieve the necessary api url.