# Configure redirect of all $http & $resource calls to other endpoint

Tags: angularjs, json-server

I would like to run a mock server e.g. [JSON Server](https://github.com/typicode/json-server), and switch between my real Java REST API backend and this JSON Server during development (for instance when real backend services are down). Is there a way to easily configure angular to use a different host for all request?

My setup:

- localhost:8080 - Spring MVC application, serves SPA + API
- localhost:8080/api - Spring MVC Rest API
- localhost:9090/api - JSON Server

And I would like to switch between calls to `localhost:8080/api` and `localhost:9090/api` with one singe line for whole Angular application.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17876439/configuration-file-in-angularjs

Comment: Not sure what you are using to route your requests to the said backend services, but if you are using a node/Express backend, you can set and use environment variables to detect if you are in dev and use that logic to route the requests.

Comment: Please check updated question

Comment: you need either to write your code that you can switch (that actually good practice), or you need to proxy requests (we are doing this with webpack -- just google something like 'proxy + json-server').

Comment: @PetrAveryanov: if I get it correctly, this proxy with webpack can be done if backend runs in node/uses webpack dev server?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@PetrAveryanov gave me hint. Using `json-proxy` this is as easy as launching proxy:

`json-proxy -p 8081 -f "/api=http://localhost:9090" -f "/=http://localhost:8080"`

And accessing application via port `8081`. "Regular" requests will be still passed through to `8080` (Tomcat serving Spring MVC application). All API calls will go to `9090` (JSON Server).

Answer (score 0):

We can set prefixURI variable to quickly change to pointing different API.

Usage:

```
var prefixURI ='https://••••':
//var prefixURI = '';//if you are on same port it is empty
$http.get(prefixURI+'posts');
```