# configuration file in angular js

Tags: angularjs

I want to store Url in configuration file so when I deployed this on Testing server or on Production I have to just change the url on config file not in js file but I don't know how to use configuration file in angular js

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Configuration file in AngularJS](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17876439/configuration-file-in-angularjs)

Answer (score 3):

You can use angular.constant for configurations.

```
app.constant('appConfigurations', {
    link_url: "http://localhost:8080/api",
    //For production u can simply change the link_url
    //link_url: "http://production_url/api"
});
```

Answer (score 1):

There are ways you can deal with it , but while coming to our implementation we used to do the following way

1. Create an External Environment js file

   ```
   (function (window) {
     window.__env = window.__env || {};

     window.__env.apiUrl = 'your Api Url';

   }(this));
   ```
2. In your Index.html

add env.js above the app.js

```
<!-- Load environment variables -->
<script src="env.js"></script>
```

3. In your app.js

   > var envr ={};
   >              if(window){
   >                Object.assign(envr,window.__env)
   >               }
   >   // Define AngularJS application var app= angular.module('myapp', []);
   >
   > // Register environment in AngularJS as constant app.constant('__env',
   >   env);

   **Update:**

For adding additional URl in Config File:

```
(function (window) {
          window.__env = window.__env || {};

          window.__env.apiUrl = 'your Api Url';

         //Another Url
         window.__env.baseUrl ='/';

        }(this));
```

Comment: If i want to store different url in external enviorment file then how can i do it?

Comment: @Leena if it helps you please mark it as Answers along with the Upvote