# Substituting JavaScript values based on Grunt task, best approach?

Tags: javascript, node.js, angularjs, gruntjs

I do not have any specific code to share as I believe the Grunt configuration of tasks is fairly straightforward.

What I would like to ask is for recommendations on replacing JavaScript variables (contained within a JavaScript `/src` folder) with new values based on the chosen Grunt task.

Specifically, I have a `Shared.js` (AngularJS Factory) that contains information critical to the application working (ex. locations of Web Services, Whether authentication is enabled, etc.).

Would it make more sense to "build" a new `Shared.js` depending on the task (i.e. swap in `dev-Shared.js` if the task is "dev") or should I use Grunt's "string-replace" to crawl through each JavasSript file and replace these values?

I would appreciate your recommendations and comments and any code snippets that you have time to provide. :)

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16339595/angular-js-configuration-for-different-enviroments

Comment: Thanks for the link - very helpful so far.