# Grunt - How to manage both client-side and server side development?

Tags: gruntjs, client-side, server-side

I'm developing my first web app, using *grunt*, *yo*, *angular.js*, ... I also need some server-side service (which I will implement in *PHP*).

Which is the "standard" way to handle this scenario, which is - I suppose - quite widespread?
I mean, a setup which can be used both during development (*grunt* server for client-side, and *apache* for server-side) and production (*apache* or *nginx* server for both client-side and server side).

I make an example to clarify my doubts: I have an angular service like this:

```
var serverUrl = '//localhost:80';
app.factory('myFactory', function($resource) {
    $resource(serverUrl + '/api/getDataFromServer/:reqId', { ... }
);
```

While developing, I have two distinct servers for client-side (*grunt* on port 9000, for example), and server-side (*apache* on port 80, for example), so - to avoid CORS issues - I will have to - at least - add a `header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin: http://localhost:9000")` to server (*JSON*) output.

In production, conversely, I will have a single server to serve both static (angular app) and dynamic (data from *PHP*) content, so I will not need any additional *Access-Control* meta tag...

Of course I can take the current environment status (*development* / *production*) into account, and accordingly output or not the additional meta tag...

My question is: is this approach common with web apps (which need custom data services)?
Do you follow a different approach, or do you see any 'architectural' improvement possible with this design?

Comment: Just a bit of info about an approach I took. I've used a combination of https://github.com/alanshaw/grunt-include-replace and https://github.com/changer/grunt-targethtml to help facilitate this kind of thing, but that was more about editing HTML. I call 'grunt dev' or 'grunt production' to do things differently in each scenario. Usually I have that many different DBs and potential deployment URLs I manually alter those in JS and Web.config, so nothing too sophisticated.

Comment: Thanks... I did just found also this SO answer: http://stackoverflow.com/a/18343298/709439, which I found very straightforward to differentiate among different environments directly inside Gruntfile.js. However, my question was more about  the overall architecture...