# Angular environment variable and visual studio 2017

Tags: c#, angular, visual-studio

I need to load my ApIEndPoint in an Angular 5 client depending on the hosting environment (development / production).

I have seen some examples that rely on a `src` folder when the Angular app template is generated by the Angular CLI. However, I do not use the Angular CLI. I rather rely on the Angular template generated by Visual Studio and add the components / services manually.

There are `Environment` files under `node_modules\@schematics\angular\application\files\__sourcedir__\` but I'm not sure I can modify those files or add new ones. This is the nodes package folder after all that may be overwritten when I upgrade my node version.

How can I safely add environment files to my project when not using the Angular CLI to create my files?

Comment: Hi, kind of duplicated by [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16339595/how-do-i-configure-different-environments-in-angular-js)

Comment: @nilsK:  I'm not using angular.js