# How to create this global constant to be shared among controllers in Angularjs?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-service

Suppose I want to make this a variable a constant to be shared among controllers in Angularjs;

```
$webroot = "localhost/webroot/app"
```

After some investigation, it seems services are the way to do. But what is the best way? Do I use a factory, service, value or something else?

The services.js from angularjs-master-seed is below;

```
angular.module('myApp.services', []).value('version', '0.1');
```

How do I modify it to have a constant $webroot that is sharable among controllers?

Can I do the following?

```
angular.module('myApp.services', [])
        .value('version', '0.1')
        .constant('webroot','localhost/webroot/app');
```

If it is ok, how do I call it in the controller?

Comment: If you only want to share a single variable only then why do not you go for $rootScope it can be used across all controller too, its good ides to share function in services else you can go with $rootScope also, Just a thought

Comment: usually you put value/constant in the main module it's quite wrong what you are doing

Comment: Using `$rootScope` is akin to using a global in vanilla javascript. It's considered a bad practice and creates a dependency to `$rootScope` from every controller and service that needs the variable.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If your variable have a constant value or is set once `value` is the right choice.
You can define it like this:

```
app = angular.module('myApp', []);
app.value('$webroot', 'localhost/webroot/app');
```

Now you can inject the service to your controller and use it:

```
app.controller('myController', ['$scope', '$webroot', function($scope, $webroot) {
  $scope.webroot = $webroot;
}]);
```

**Edit #1**
To fit your updated question: You can use a constant the same way as a value:

```
app = angular.module('myApp', []);
app.constant('$webroot', 'localhost/webroot/app');

app.controller('myController', ['$scope', '$webroot', function($scope, $webroot) {
  $scope.webroot = $webroot;
}]);
```

Comment: How about using app.constant?

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13015523/angular-js-is-value-the-proper-way-to-set-app-wide-constant-and-how-to-retri

Comment: `value`can only be injected into services and controllers while `constant` can also be injected into the module `config` function. If he does not need to do that I see no compelling reason to use `constant` over `value`.

Comment: value can be edited by controller. Constant is not editable. If intention is not to be editable, then constant may be better.

Comment: In that case, I *do* see a compelling reason to use `constant`. I didn't know it was mutable as a `value` (never tried changing it)

Comment: I think you'll be fine with both, because they are just slight different. I prefer `value` because I can change it easly in the test suit.

Comment: I have a follow-up question to your answer. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22710593/how-to-create-a-global-object-with-properties-that-are-sharable-among-controller

Answer (score 4):

Whats happens when you want more constants? How about adding a config object that you can inject wherever needed. As its a single file it's also much easier to have dev.config and prod.config files that can be swapped in and out at build time.

```
app.factory('Config', function(){
    return{
        webRoot: "localhost/webroot/app",
        moreSettings: "abc"
    };
});
```