# where to store global data in angular JS?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

In angular Js i am trying to store user data such as profile name that should exist in most of routes is it a good practice to store them in the `$rootScope`. IF not where should i store them.

Comment: There are a few answers to this question here that may help:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22707699/how-to-create-this-global-constant-to-be-shared-among-controllers-in-angularjs/22708212#22708212

Answer (score 3):

If you use a service it's everywhere available and if it should be persistent over page reloads and so on, then you can store the data in local storage or a cookie etc. and access it with your service on load.

```
angular.module('app')
  .factory('UserService', ['SessionService', function(SessionService) {
       SessionService.load();
       var user = SessionService.getUser();

       var service = {
           setUser: function(u){ user = u; },
           getUser: function(){ return user; }
       };
       return service;
   }])
   .controller('DemoCtrl', ['$scope', 'UserService', function($scope, UserService){
       $scope.user = UserService.getUser();
   }]);
```

Comment: i have a session service that contains that data and a cookie for handling refresh but i will need to inject that service in every view is that right way of doing it.

Comment: Yes, you need to inject the service into every controller.

Answer (score 0):

I'm new to angular myself but the route I'm taking is to write a service. You could have a service that stores the user profile data. I would maybe put a method on the service to load the profile data and then store it locally in the service. You could then get this information via a getter method.

Comment: thanks for you help. That's what i had implemented, i am asking for a better way i heard about something called application controller that is being defined on the body tag