# Export variables in JavaScript with Angular?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I'm creating an App that different customers should use. The things that will differ between the customers is for example the brand name and the server URL.

I have seen the `constant()` method, but I don't really understand it.

For example:

```
<body>
    Welcome to {{brandName}} homepage. 
    We use the server {{server.url}} for our REST calls.
</body>
```

I'm thinking a file `conf.js`

```
var brandName = "Örkelljunga IF"
var server = {
    "url": "Orkelljunga.com",
    "otherinfo" : "Other Information"
}
export.brandName = brandName;
export.server = server;
```

And then access it from constant()? How do I achieve this?

Any examples and maybe best practices in Angular?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
angular
  .constant("myConfig", export)
  .controller("mainCtrl", function ($scope, myConfig) {
    $scope.brandName = myConfig.brandName;
    $scope.server = myConfig.server;
  });
```

Answer (score 1):

You can make a controller and bind this data to $scope. Something like this:

```
var myApp = angular.module('myApp',[]);

myApp.controller('MyController', ['$scope', function($scope) {
  $scope.brandName = "Örkelljunga IF"
  $scope.server = {
    "url": "Orkelljunga.com",
    "otherinfo" : "Other Information"
  }
}]);
```

You'll have to include following in your html too.

```
<html lang="en" data-ng-app="myApp">
```

and

```
<div ng-controller="MyController">
  Welcome to {{brandName}} homepage. 
  We use the server {{server.url}} for our REST calls.
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can add a simple config object that you inject wherever it is needed. [Take a look at this question/answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22707699/how-to-create-this-global-constant-to-be-shared-among-controllers-in-angularjs/22708212#22708212):