# Access config constants inside view in angularjs

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-scope, web-analytics

I've configured a constant on a module like below(simplified version of my actual scenario):

```
var app = angular.module('app', []);
angular.config('AnalyticsConstant', function(){
  property: {
    click: 'clicked',
    swipe: 'swiped',
    externalLink: 'opened external link'        
  },
  page: {
    message: {
    list: 'Message listing',
    show: 'Message show'
    }
  }
}
```

Now I based on user action taken (say swipe), I want to trigger an analytics  event. Since swipe/click or recognizing if an element has an external link, is something done on view level, I want to pass a hash to my controller method.

for example:

```
 <ion-list>
  <ion-item ng-repeat="message in messages track by $index" ui-sref="message_path({id: message.id})" class="item-text-wrap">
    <my-track-directive source='message', property='click'>
  </ion-item>  
 </ion-list>
```

Here certainly in myTrackDirective, I can read these two values and check if source/property key is available in AnalyticsConstant. Once found out, I'll also have to check if the value are key another key in AnalyticsConstant.source/property hash. Another pain will be, I'll need to stringify the keys source/property so that I can check in hash, however that's not a problem.

I was wondering if I can access the AnalyticsConstant in view, so that the directive line becomes something like:

```
    <my-track-directive source='AnalyticsConstant[page][message][list]', userAction='AnalyticsConstant[property][click]'>
```

I could think of three solutions:

- *Add inject it root scope. ie.*

`app.run(function($rootScope, AnalyticsConstant){
         $rootScope.analyticsConstant = AnalyticsConstant
     }`

But this is not a good solution, as if by mistake anyone changes `$rootScope.analyticsConstant` to something else, whole functionality may get screwed.

- *Inject in each controller and set it at $scope level.*

`$scope.analyticsConstant = AnalyticsConstant`

This will be a lot of duplication. Also, it'll also not ensure if `$scope.analyticsConstant` won't get corrupted by mistake.(Though disaster will also be scoped and limited :) )

- *Write a function which returns AnalyticsConstant inside 'module.run' or may be inside each controller.*

`function getAnalyticsConstant = function(){
       return AnalyticsConstant
    }`

I particularly liked the third approach. But question remains where to place this (rootScope or controller-scope)?

### My questions are:

1. Is there any better way to access configured constant inside view in angular?
2. What might be other problems with each of these approach I listed above?
3. Is the directive approach is better or should I collect this data in some model and then pass it to analytics event function ?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would use `value` to define constants:

```
app.value('AnalyticsConstant', function(){
  property: {
    click: 'clicked',
    swipe: 'swiped',
    externalLink: 'opened external link'        
  },
  page: {
    message: {
    list: 'Message listing',
    show: 'Message show'
    }
  }
}
```

So in each controller/directive you just nee to create instance, for example:

```
app.directive('myTrackDirective', ['AnalyticsConstant', function(AnalyticsConstant) {
        return {
            restrict: 'E',
            replace: true,
             scope: {/* ... */},
            templateUrl: 'some.html',

            link: function(scope) {
              scope.AnalyticsConstant = AnalyticsConstant;
            }
        };
    }]);
```

After you can call `AnalyticsConstant` from HTML

---

As a side note (doesn't refer to question):

Try to use <kbd>[MixPanel](http://mixpanel.com)</kbd>. Works great for Cordova-Ionic-Angular

Comment: Isn't that what can be done using config as well? Though yes, putting AnalyticsConstant inside isolated scope can ensure it doesn't get changed inadvertently +1 for this :).

Comment: @Indyarocks Actually you need *read only* behaviour. `app.config` has other goals then storage of constants

Comment: Btw, according to this discussion on [constant, value](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13015523/angular-js-is-value-the-proper-way-to-set-app-wide-constant-and-how-to-retri) ,  shouldn't we use app.constant() in place of app.value() . Correct me if I'm missing anything here! Thanks for your last comment :)

Comment: @Indyarocks you can use `constant`. There is no big difference. Only if you want constant to be injected into  a module configuration function when `value` - no